# How to custom the map controller in Windows Phone to use my Map image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a Map App for our school. Our school provide me its own map image and coordinate information. So I want use my map image as the source of map and accord to user's location to show a point in the map image. Can anybody gives me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. It is possible to change the source of the map-tiles (e.g. from Bing to say Nokia or Google) of the [Map Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941096%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). However, for this to work, it is important that map-tiles source implements mechanisms like quadkeys (e.g. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx)). Therefore, to answer your question if you would like to use the Bing Map Control with your school's map so that you can leverage the positioning features of the control, it would require that you have a map-tile server properly designed in order to achieve this. AND, there might be some legal issue with altering the Bing Map control if i am not mistaken.
2. However, given that you are suggesting an image of the map and then doing positioning, then i would suggest that it can be as easy as you calibrating the pixel X-Y coordinate system on the map with that of the geo-coordinate provided by the geo-watcher. Then, in your code you could do a simple mapping between these 2 systems and then draw something on top of the image. For this part you could use a `writeablebitmap` or simply use the fact that you can overlay UI controls with silverlight. So, for the latter have a canvas with the an image of the map of your school and then on top of that canvas you can have an `<image>` representing the device and change its top-left coordinate wrt to the canvas.

   So, in summary, as the geo-watcher gives geo x-y coordinates to your code, there is mapping function to the pixel X-Y (which you have pre-calculated) and use that XY to position an overlay `<image>` or draw some "pin" on a `writeablebitmap` where you have previously draw the image of the map of your school. Things get complicated with this approach when you want to have zooming as well but, this solution is easily scalable.

Does this help clear things a bit?

**Answering 2nd question in comment below:**

Yes you can zoom in and out of the canvas but, you would have to program it yourself. The control itself, the canvas does not have this capability. Hence, you would have to recognize the triggers for a zoom action (e.g. clicking on the (+) or (-) buttons or, pinch and stretch gestures) and react to that by re-drawing on the canvas a portion of the region on the canvas so that now that regions stretches over the entire canvas. That is, zooming. For instance for the zoom in case: you would have to determine a geometrical area which corresponds to the zoom factor and is in ratio to the dimensions of the canvas object. Then, you would have to scale that portion up so that edges and empty spaces representing walls and spaces between them grow proportionately. Also, you have to determine the center point of that region which your fix on the canvas so that everything grows away from it. Hence, you would be achieving a appropriate zooming effect. At this point you would have to re-adjust your mapping function of geo-coordinates to pixel XY so that the "pin" or object of interest can be drawn with precision and accurately on the newly rendered surface.

I understand that this can appear quite intensive but, it is straightforward once you appreciate for yourself the mechanics of what is required.

Another easier option could be to use SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) in a Web-Browser control. Note that you would still require the geo-coordinate to pixel-xy system. However, with this approach you can get the zooming for free with the combination of SVG (which have transformation capabilities for the scale up and down operations) and Web-Browser which enables you to render the SVG and does the gesture handling of zooming in to the map. For that, i believe that the cost of work would be in re-creating the map of your school which is in bitmap to SVG. There are tools like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) which you can use to load the image of your map and then trace the outlines over it. You can then save that outline document as an SVG. In fact, i would recommend this approach to your problem before tackling the Canvas method as i feel that it would be the easiest path for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, since I need an offline solution I will try the second way you mentioned. I have considered that use a <image> label to present the map, but without your recommendation I don't know how to set the focus point of the image. I wonder that if I can zoom in and out in the canvas?

Comment: Yes you can. I updated the answer above to answer to that question.

Comment: Thank you, what a kind man you are! I have implement the zoom code and set any point to the center of the canvas. Thank you. When I move my image by touch it, for example, I touch the image and hold on and move up towards. The program title will be covered by part of my map image which moved out of the canvas. Do you know how to restrict the image that if some parts are out of canvas, these parts become transparent just like they are covered by title panel?

Comment: One trick you can employ is the zindex of the controls. That is, in your XAML (or the document model of your user interface) controls that are lower in the XAML page would appear on top of controls that are higher in a given container. So, if you have a container like <grid> and inside you have <canvas> and then <textblock> (which you use for title), then the title would appear on top of the canvas in case there are overlaps. On the other hand if <textblock> was followed by <canvas> then your title would be obscured (as is the case now). So, reverse their order in the XAML it should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that the LayoutClip also can solve my problem:<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="MyRectangleGeometry"
                                   Rect="0,0,451,456"
                />
            </Grid.Clip>
            <canvas>..</canvas>
        </Grid>